# Paypal-Express gem Rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am trying to implement the paypal express payment using paypal-express gem. However, am confused.

Here is the code for the create method in the  transaction controller

```
      elsif params[:purchase][:payment_method] == "Paypal"
          #paypal payment
          request = Paypal::Express::Request.new(
              :username   => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              :password   => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
              :signature  => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                )
                payment_request = Paypal::Payment::Request.new(
                  :currency_code => "#{@current_user.currency}",   # if nil, PayPal use USD as default
                  :description   => "Purchase of SMS",    # item description
                  :quantity      => 1,      # item quantity
                  :amount        => "#{@total}",   # item value
                )
                response = request.setup(
                  payment_request,
                  success_url,
                cancel_url
                )
                transaction.tracking_id = response.token 
                transaction.save
                response.redirect_uri
```

And success method

```
  def success   
    token = params[:token]
    payer_id = params[:payer_id]
    request = Paypal::Express::Request.new(
                  :username   => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  :password   => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                  :signature  => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    )
    response = request.details(token)
    transaction = Transaction.find_by_tracking_id(token)
    transaction.merchant_reference = payer_id
    transaction.status = "Completed"
    transaction.save
    user = User.find(transaction.user_id)
        user.balance = (user.balance+response.amount.to_i)
        user.save()
        response = request.checkout!(
      token,
      payer_id,
      payment_request
        )
      flash[:notice] = 'Payment Transaction Completed'
      user_home_path(@current_user)   
  end
```

and cancel method

```
 def cancel   
      flash[:warn] = 'Payment Request Canceled'
      user_home_path(@current_user)     
  end
```

How can i make a proper request in the create method, obtain a token as a response and store it so am able to to use it in the success method to search for the particular transaction.

Also, how can i then execute a proper `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` in the success method.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the paypal-express gem so I am a little confused about how the create method can make use of response.token (third line from the bottom: transaction.tracking_id = response.token).  That assignment feels early in the process.

Regardless, your question has little to do with the gem and more to do with your application.  Your underlying question is "How can I persist data between two or more actions?"  As I see it, you have two possible approaches.

First, you could put the response.token or transaction.tracking_id into session.  If the user making the payment is NOT a part of every visit to your website then this approach may not work.

Second, you could store the token/tracking_id on whatever DB-backed model you're using to track the order.  This way you can go look up the active order based on the token/tracking_id and have your application's context for the Paypal response.

Comment: that line was just a gamble.. just copied the code in my confused state.

Comment: @pwz2000, i got it working long ago..i just used NVP classic API long ago